# Application's required .Net Framework version is 4 but when trying to run it wants 4.5

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0, windows-xp, .net-4.5

Firstly I coded my application using .Net Framework 4.5 in Win 7 system. When I realize [.Net Framework 4.5 doesn't support Win XP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8z6watww%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) I downgraded version to 4. But when I install my application any Win XP Sp3 system and try to run it, I get below error message. I checked all projects **Target framework** value from **Properties** window and they already set as **.Net Framework 4.**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found the cause of the problem! I have set all projects "**Target framework**" value as 4.0, but ***in app.config file there was a overlooked restriction definition*** like

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
```

I found required value [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx) and changed definition like

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
```

Now, it works seamlessly on Win XP Sp3.